# CSharp ado.net Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

suppose I have a table with 3 column

```
   ID       Int
   Name     nvarchar(63)
   Age      Int
```

and I have a procedure to search all row match with keyword input.

```
Create Procedure usp_Search

 @KeyWord nvarchar(63)
as
begin
    SEKECT * FROM TblPersonal
             WHERE 
                   @KeyWord IS NULL
                OR @KeyWord  = Age
                OR Name Like N'%'+@KeyWord+'%'  
end
```

when I tested with SQl management tool it work fine

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Search]
        @KeyWord = NULL
```

BUT when execute in ADO.net and pass `DBNull.Value` to SqlParameter  I had error

> *"Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"*

anyone can tell me what different ADO.net and Environment of  SQl management tool

Answer (score 1):

the problem is on this line:

```
OR @KeyWord  = Age
```

The column `Age` is an integer and `@KeyWord` is string. To prevent from getting the error, convert the data type of `age` into string,

```
OR @KeyWord  = CAST(Age AS NVARCHAR(5))
```

Answer (score -1):

try configure your *sql* server management..
in tools - option - designers - uncheck  "prevent saving changes..."